# Windows -- how to find the maximum number of processes of a single image name

Tags: windows, process

I am trying to figure out how many processes I can create of a single image name (i.e. "something.exe"). I see that when I practically try to create as many as I can, I get to around 150 (far less than the total overall processes that can be run by my machine). Figuring out the number by actual experimentation this way, however, is resource intensive and slow. I've searched all that I can on the subject and I can't seem to find anyone addressing this issue. A command line call or something of the sort would be great.

Comment: What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve? Each hardware has different limits and creating the maximum number of .exe-s is not a good approach for pretty much any problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm creating a utility to do a serious of benchmarks on a system, so in this particular case there's no big issue with running tests that really load it down.

Comment: That's fine but you haven't answered the question. A benchmark still shouldn't try to create an unbounded number of processes. If you try to load the system to see how much it can take, start creating threads and keep measuring CPU load and determine if you can create more threads.